# control java instance by (java script) interfaces from shell script?

Tags: java, javascript, python, bash

I am absolutely new to java and am referring to a program energy2d. Its source code is [here](https://github.com/charxie/energy2d).

It is run as an embeded applet(see at the website link in github, as I am not allowed to post more then one url)
(functions with default locale for the browser)
or on the command line:

```
java -jar /home/ntu/Downloads/energy2d.jar
```

And there are some commands for it, -I call them control interfaces further on, I guess they are some public methods but do not know the exact term for them - that control the program at runtime. see website manual scripts.html

One can use them from inside the program in a embedded shell or you can see how they are called in the source of the website from java script at the embedded applet.

I do not understand that well, it should just demonstrate that
for example the string "reload" as a occurrence of the control interfaces is used in the page*s source.
To my current knowledge I can not make out where they are defined; it is at github   Scripter2D.java#L55 where I loose track within the java-code. (do not know if this helps)

Now, what I want is to call these control interfaces from within an outside script. Let's say a bash script; well in the end I want it run python.

something like command line pseudo code:

snippet start

```
java -jar /home/ntu/Downloads/energy2d.jar #to start the application
java -do_to_running_program energy2d.jar -public_control_function load path/new_config.xml#to load another configuration file
java -_do_to_running_program -public_control_function run #to restart
```

snippet end

Questions:
-how is that achievable?
-If it is not possible:
what would be a good practice to change the java code in order to have this working?

Any hints will be thanked.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: by 'java script', you actually mean that you want to provide some service-interface to your java applet which is accessible by other processes (local or remote), and that this service-interface could be driven by a script.

If so, then yes, it's achievable -- file watching and jmx come to mind.  Your biggest concern should be security (eg, there's this: https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/browser/java_jre17_jmxbean).  Having your applet expose such an interface is ok for testing I guess (but unit testing is almost always better); however, I strongly advise against exposing such interfaces in the final applet.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I try to be the most precise: The case it that I am only the user of this program, I am not the author. The author is running the same code on the website and as well offers it as a jar file. The applet is running on a website, yes, but I want it running as a local binary. [link](http://energy.concord.org/energy2d/manual/scripts.html) given these functions are already implemented as "service-interface" as the site states: "The Scripting User Interface (SUI) of Energy2D allows it to communicate with external programs such as JavaScript." what would then be the calling syntax?

Comment: oh ok.  Just from grepping through the energy2d applet source, it appears it will execute any script supplied with the 'script' parameter to the applet. It retrieves this parameter using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks for that. Given the non-web side of the application, what be the effort to implement such a jmx-service-interfaces-mechanism to the existing code? Let's say there might be a jmx-pyhton lib around for that. - Anyway I searched the internet and rarely found something, some tutorial or the like, on that...